# Сложение четных чисел, пока не появится пустая строка

Tags: python

На вход с клавиатуры подаются числа (по одному). Нужно вывести на экран сумму всех четных чисел. Ввод прекращается, если введена пустая строка (""). При любой ситауации, когда не попадаются четные числа, вывести на экран нужно 0 (например, числа не были введены вообще или были введены только нечетные числа).

```
summ = 0

while 1:
    a = int(input())
    if a == ('') : break;
    for i in range(a):
        if  i % 2 == 0:
            summ += i    
print(summ)
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Как сделать так, что бы ввод заканчивался на пустой строке. Выдает ошибку что пустая строка, это не целое число. Как их связать?

Comment: Если ввести с клавиатуры 8 и 9 программа считает сумму 32. Нужно ещё какое-то условие.

Comment: Да нет, выдает только 8.

Comment: А если ничего не ввести или ввести только нечëтные числа?

Comment: @Оля тогда выдаст 0

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. А как в итоге получилось? Без цикла?

Comment: @Оля https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150736/397034 вот правильный код

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант

```
summ = 0
a = 0
while a != "":
    if int(a) % 2 == 0:
        summ += int(a)
    a = input()
print(summ)
```

Comment: почему-то не правильно считает, пока не понял почему)

Comment: Ещё раз глянул условия и сам код, так там же цикл не нужен) Ответ обновил

Comment: да, можно обойтись и без него, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 8):

Проблема в том, что вы сначала делаете приведение ввода к числу, а потом проверяете, что было введено. Естественно, пустую строку в число преобразовать нельзя и возникает ошибка. Стоит перенести приведение ввода к числу в другое место:

```
summ = 0

while True:
    a = input()
    if not a:
        break
    for i in range(int(a)):
        if  i % 2 == 0:
            summ += i

print(summ)
```

Либо сделать ещё проще:

```
result = sum(filter(lambda x: not x % 2, map(int, iter(input, ''))))
print(result)
```

Comment: Если я меняю первую и вторую строчку в цикле while, то он пишет, что a не определена. Если её задать перед циклом, то опять получается та же ошибка. Писать код в строчку мне пока рано)

Comment: Потому что надо считывание ввода и преобразование в число разбить на две разных операции.

Comment: 'while a == "":
    for i in range(int(a)):'
Сделал так, работает, но считает не верно)

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Подумайте над логикой работы вашего скрипта.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = sum(x for x in map(int, iter(input, '')) if not x % 2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Тогда уж и от map стоило включение избавиться, чтобы не мешать разные подходы.